# How do I use a command in a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to use a command that I have created. I am using c# and the MVVM structure for my application. I have 1 Window (ApplicationView) that is used to display my userContols(MainWindow, Window1). On startup I have the MainWindow user control showing and there is a button on that user control that when you press will change the user contol from the main window usercontol to the Window1 userContol.

ApplicationView.xaml(Window)

```
<Window x:Class="Nmenq.ApplicationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nmenq"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Nmenq"
    Title="ApplicationView" Height="400" Width="575">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Window1ViewModel}">
        <local:Window1/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ContentControl x:Name="Pages" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

ApplicationView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ApplicationView : Window
{
    public ApplicationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new NavigationViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml(UserContol)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nmenq.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nmenq"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Nmenq.ViewModel"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Nmenq"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="575">


<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <Button x:Name="Accept_Button" Content="Accept" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="475,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Command="{Binding Window1Command}"/>   
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xmal.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    NavigationViewModel object1 = new NavigationViewModel();

    public ICommand Window1Command { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window1Command = object1.Window1Command;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationViewModel(Where My command is set up)

```
    class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MainWindowCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand Window1Command { get; set; }

    private object currentPageViewModel;
    public object CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return currentPageViewModel; }
        set { currentPageViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel"); }
    }

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        MainWindowCommand = new BaseCommand(OpenMainWindow);
        Window1Command = new BaseCommand(OpenWindow1);

        CurrentPageViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    }

    public void OpenMainWindow(object obj)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    public void OpenWindow1(object obj)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = new Window1ViewModel();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _method;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
        : this(method, null)
    {
    }

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _method = method;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _method.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}    class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MainWindowCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand Window1Command { get; set; }

    private object currentPageViewModel;
    public object CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return currentPageViewModel; }
        set { currentPageViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel"); }
    }

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        Window1Command = new BaseCommand(OpenWindow1);

        CurrentPageViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    }

    public void OpenWindow1(object obj)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = new Window1ViewModel();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _method;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
        : this(method, null)
    {
    }

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _method = method;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _method.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

Any Help or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind directly to the `Window1Command` property of the `NavigationViewModel` and remove the `Window1Command` property from the `UserControl`:

```
<Button x:Name="Accept_Button" Content="Accept" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="475,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.Window1Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. By doing that it now works many thanks for your advice